# Vue.js - Add or set new data to array in store

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have two Vue components that use a common array set in a store like this:

```
var store = {
    state: {
        myArray: []
    }
};

var FirstComp = Vue.extend({
    template: '#first-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            arrayData: store.state.myArray
        };
    }
});

/* A second component quite identical */
```

I followed the example given in the [Vue js guide](http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State-Management).

I'm trying to update the data in the array in the store with new data from another array (after an ajax call), so that it impacts both components. I would like to have a nice way of replacing / concating the old array with a new one. I know I can't just replace the array like this `store.state.myArray = newArrayData;`because I would loose the Vue binding. But [the method given in the docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array) (at least for concat) doesn't work in the case of the store (or maybe I'm missing something?).

Right now, the only way I've found is to use a foreach with `push`, `$remove`or `$set` depending on the operation and it is not that elegant and practical.

For example, for concat, I do this:

```
$.each(newArray, function (i, val) {
    store.state.myArray.push(val);
});
```

But for replacing it gets uglier. What would be the proper way to this?

(For info, I'm not using Vuex for state management and I don't plan to at the moment, I'm keeping it very simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the assignment work you can just use "state" in your component like this:

```
var FirstComp = Vue.extend({
    template: '#first-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            state: store.state
        };
    }
});
```

And then use `state.myArray`. This way if you will do `store.state.myArray = newValue` it won't break the binding.

Comment: Thanks, It's working perfectly! I knew I was missing something quite obvious, but couldn't figure out what, now I understand.